# I tried to use git to return to a previous commit, but now some node_modules aren't working. Why is that?

Tags: git, react-native, commit

This is a react native project.

I'm guessing I did something wrong with git, because I'm now getting errors about node_modules that worked since I began working on this project.

Here are the commands I ran:

```
  450* git checkout 'removed for security, but was the hash'
  451* git checkout master
  452* git stash
  453* git reset --hard 'removed for security, but was the hash'
  454* runios 8 (an alias we added ourselves, launches the app in the simulator)
  456* yarn
  457  yarn start
```

Comment: whats the error code? Did you already tried deleting your node modules folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reinstall for the original commit using the package.json file.

1. `git checkout` the commit you want to try
2. remove entire `node_modules/` directory
3. `yarn install` (`npm install` for npm fans) based on the package.json file at that time

When I give someone a node repo I always remove or exclude `node_modules/` and the recipient just does the install for their OS, versions, etc.  Otherwise my code is easily 100+ times larger. This is a common practice.

What may have happened in your case is that an older version has different package dependencies from the current ones installed.

By `removing node_modules/` and doing the install again you can resolve the problem.

As for Git, you may need to do a catchup commit for the resolution.
btw I keep node_modules in my `.gitignore` file and that is also a common practice.  However it does mean that when you switch commits you may need to go through the above procedures to align your node_module version package correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem with your local git... But an easy solution is to do yarn install (in your project root).

yarn install is used to install all dependencies for a project. The dependencies are retrieved from your project’s package.json file, and stored in the yarn.lock file.

Do it and you will have your node_modules folder again. Anyways you can try to merge the last version of your project where the folder wasn’t deleted.

But I recommend the first way.